# Why int data type is behaving like this in JAVA?

Tags: java, types

Below is my code and its output but I couldn't understand why it is giving such output. Can anyone help me to understand the output?

```
public class MainClass1 
{
       double overloadedMethod(double d) {
              System.out.println("double " + d);
              return overloadedMethod(d *= d);
       }

       static int overloadedMethod(int i) {
              System.out.println("int " + i);
              return overloadedMethod(i *= i);
       }

       float overloadedMethod(float f) {
              System.out.println("float " + f);
              return overloadedMethod(f *= f);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
              MainClass1 mc = new MainClass1();
              int jj = 300;
              System.out.println(mc.overloadedMethod(jj));
       }
}
```

Output:-

```
int 300
int 90000
int -489934592
int 560005120
int 0
int 0
int 0
int 0
.
.
.
```

And it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: because you are doing an infinite loop calling `overloadedMethod` that calls itself, that calls itself, that...

Comment: recursion without possibility to break out of it will do that

Comment: Did you try a debugger? This is an excellent opportunity if you haven’t already learnt to use one.

Comment: Which output had you expected?

Comment: Please post actual code. Your code produce different output.

Comment: @OleV.V : Check now i updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are first calling `overloadedMethod(int i)` passing an argument of 300. this prints:

```
int 300
```

Then `i *= i` multiplies `i` with `i` and stores the result, 90 000, back into `i`. Then you call the same method again with this as argument. This is known as recursion. So the new invocation of the method prints:

```
int 90000
```

Next time you again square. You might have expected 8 100 000 000 as result, but an `int` cannot hold this value. It overflows. Unfortunately you get no message about this in Java. Instead the result is

```
int -489934592
```

The next few multiplications overflow too, but then the result after overflow happens to be 0:

```
int 0
```

From this point the multiplication doesn’t overflow anymore, it just yields 0 each time.

And you never get out of the recursion. It continues until your call stack overflows. This is known as infinite recursion.

Did you expect that Java would see that 8 100 000 000 isn’t an `int` and then call the overloaded method taking a `float` or `double` argument? As you see, this doesn’t happen. Java decides *on compile time*  which overloaded method to call. So it doesn’t take the value of the argument into account (which is already truncated to -489 934 592 anyway, so it also wouldn’t help). Since `i` is an `int`, `overloadedMethod(i *= i)` always calls `overloadedMethod(int i)`. Never any of the other `overloadedMethod`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It is really very helpful.

Comment: 300 is divisible by 4. So on the first call, its lowest two bits are zero. On each call, the value is squared so the binary representation of the value has twice as many of its lowest bits set to zero, (2,4,8,16,32) so after five iterations all the bits are zero. Using a number which is relatively prime to 2³² should not end up at zero, but may end up at another stable point of i = i*i mod 2³².

Comment: …also known as an odd number. Thanks for providing the explanation, @PeteKirkham

Answer (score 0):

you have an infinite loop here:

```
    static int overloadedMethod(int i) {
      System.out.println("int " + i);
      return overloadedMethod(i *= i);
    }
```

return statement calling it's method.

Comment: Correction: infinite *recursion*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i cound't understand why it is giving -489934592,560005120 and fall down to 0.

Comment: @VihangShah maybe next time say in the question what exactly it is that confuses you. As you can see, everybody was focusing on the infinite recursion because they thought you didn't expect infinite system outputs, when actually all you wanted to know is why the printed value is not `8100000000`. This is why everybody asked what you expected the output to be, but unfortunately you didn't answer them